# Cannot add additional Google account for Gmail on Android 13-based phone

Tags: gmail, google-account

I am trying to add an additional Google account to Gmail on an Android 13-based phone. While adding an account, I asked for a security code. But when I try to enter the value of the security code (10 digits) from

**Settings | Google account | Manage Google account | Security**

I got the message "wrong code" - tried several times but without success.

Do I miss something or there is a known issue? Previously I succeeded in performing similar on an Android 11-based phone and was not asked for a security code.

Comment: You need to use the code from a phone where that Google account is already logged in, not from the same phone as the code belongs to a different account.

Comment: Thanks , for reply , I understand . But when I am adding new acount and it does not exists on that phone - I asked for credentials of  this new mail and then asked for the code - do I performing  something wrong ? Thanks

Comment: The account you want to add is configured to use a security code and it seems to have at least one active device - at least from Google perspective. May be you have already reset that device while being offline then you have a problem any may need to contact Google support.